# dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies

Tags: debian, dpkg, software-packaging

I am trying to build my debian package using dpkg-buildpackage in automatic manner. This is my workflow:

```
dpkg-buildpackage || (yes | mk-build-deps -i && dpkg-buildpackage)
```

This unfortunatelly gives me

> dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: python-virtualenv
>   python-dev libssl-dev python-m2crypto virtualenv libffi-dev

I know, I can run add `apt-get install` and those packages to my script, but once I change build deps, I have to change the script. Is there any way how to do this automatically?

Comment: This is [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416517/286615) I used. The *magic* part was: `mk-build-deps --install --root sudo --remove` which takes care of the additional steps that would otherwise be required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `mk-build-deps` to automatically download and build the dependencies for you